# Linq Total of a Group

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a List of Person and each person has an Color.Name

I need to basically get a simple object like :

```
 "Blue", 50
 "Green", 70
```

Etc

```
List<Person> people....;

people.GroupBy(p=>p.Color.name)    ?????
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Select`

```
List<Person> people....;

people.GroupBy(p=>p.Color.name)
      .Select(g => new { Color = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

You can replace `new { Color = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }` with anything you like to get the desired output, like `"\"" + g.Key + "\", " + g.Count()` to get exactly the string listing you have in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Having a GroupBy produces objects with a `Key` property and an Enumerable of the objects within each Group. The Key can either be a simple type like a `string` or a complex object (like a Person).

So the following, for each Group, it will get you the name (x.Key) and the Count of the objects within that group (color name).

```
people.GroupBy(p=>p.Color.name).Select(x=>new {Color = x.Key, Count= x.Count()});
```